# What is the smallest decimal that can be represented using IEEE754 single precision?

Tags: math, architecture, ieee-754

Is seems like it would be IE-38, which would make the exponent 127-127. But when I add 1E10 and 1E-32, I get 1E10 which makes me think that 1E-32 is so small it's not being properly represented.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different terms:

- minimal value representable in given format (`~10^-38`) and
- [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)  - such minimal value that `1.0 + eps != 1.0`, for single precision it is about `2^-23`

For bigger value `1e10`  minimal summand is `~1e10 * macheps`

Simplified example: for 4 decimal digits you can represent values `100.0` and `0.001`, but `100.0 + 0.001 = 100.0` because true sum `100.001` cannot fit into 4 decimal places.